# Compatibility between @ngrx/store 5.2.0 and @angular/core ^4.4.3

Tags: angular, store, ngrx, ngrx-store

Is it possible that @ngrx5.2.0 and @angular4.4.3 are not compatible?
My scenario is the following:
I just installed in my angular4.4.3 project ngrx in order to manage my state management. I practice a bit with the angular5.2.0 official boilerplate to have a bit of strcuture in my way of coding and all works.
I implemented in this production project the same way I did it in my test and this is the error I've during in compilation:

> ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /opt/webapp/node_modules/@ngrx/store/store.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in /......./app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /............./app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /........../app.module.ts

The weird thing in this error is that the mentioned versions are 4 and 3, meanwhile -I guess- they should be 5 and 4 - if the versioning is referred to angular and the store, or to the store only.

Any idea?

Comment: That error is typical when one version is not compatible with another. So, it is highly likely they are not. The lower version compiler can't handle higher version components and services.

Comment: Being in production I would like to be carful with a fast upload of angular from 4* to 5* - On the other hand, I feel I dare to try. Because I do not feel to install and use an older version of @ngrx and be dependent on a version that is not aligned with official documentation.. Let's see how it goes! I keep you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once these libraries are updated, the error disappears:

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
"ngx-webstorage": "^2.0.1",
"ts-node": "^4.1.0",
"typescript": "2.5.3"
```

So indeed, it is a matter of compatibility.

Comment: Of course after migration minor tunings on the code were done as well.